# How to hide AVPlayerViewController control bar?

Tags: ios, iad, avplayerviewcontroller

I've implemented iAd's Preroll Video Ad and I want to guarantee that my user will watch the entire advertisement. How do I hide the `AVPlayerViewController`'s control bar so the user can not tap "Done" and get out of the video before it finishes?

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;
[AVPlayerViewController preparePrerollAds];
player = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
player.showsPlaybackControls = NO;
player.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I think (didn't try) this is impossible OOTB. Your user would be stuck and couldn't cancel the whole thing (e.g. watching a video). This is not considered good UX, IMHO

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to do the same. You need to call play when you present the controller.

```
playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
if(playerItem) {
  player = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
  playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
  playerViewController.player = _player;
  [playerViewController setShowsPlaybackControls:NO];
  [parentViewController presentViewController:playerViewController animated:YES completion:^{
  [playerViewController.player play];
}];
```

Comment: Wouldn't that still show the navigation bar? The OP wants the user to be unable to close the viewController, as I understand...

Answer (score 0):

Simple code

```
// create an AVPlayer
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:videoURL];

// create a player view controller
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc]init];
controller.player = player;
controller.showsPlaybackControls = FALSE;
```