# how can I remove progress bar or video bar from a video on a tvOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tvos, tvos11

```
 @IBAction func buttonPlay(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "NORWAY", ofType: "m4v") else {
            debugPrint("video.m4v not found")
            print("video playing")
            return
        }

        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        present(controller, animated: true) {
            player.play()
            player.volume = 0
            
        }
        
    }
```

---

I want a video to be played in a loop where the user cannot forward or rewind the video.

**I want a video wallpaper but not a video player**.

video bar

[image: videoBar]

Comment: simply         `controller.showsPlaybackControls = false` ?

Comment: check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828940/how-to-hide-avplayerviewcontroller-control-bar

Comment: BUT If I use AVQueuePlayer as the player of avplayerviewcontroller, set controller.showsPlaybackControls = false in the first video, then controller.showsPlaybackControls = true in 2nd video, it will make user can't focus on playbackControls.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to hide your playback controls: `controller.showsPlaybackControls = false`

Comment: thank you so much, I also would like to know how to add text on the video and place it in center?

Comment: @Amith just create an UILabel and add as subview of your AVPlayerController view. Example: `controller.view.addSubview(label)` and set the constraints to center your label.